# Proof for any real number $c>0$ there exists $x>0$ such that $\frac{1}{x}+sinx=c$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

I have this problem:

Prove for any real number $c>0$ there exists $x>0$ so that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\sin(x)=c$

I tried to prove it, but I feel that my proof isn't entirely true.

**My proof**

$$\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{1}{x}+\sin x= +\infty$$

For $M=c>0$ there is suitable $\delta>0$ that for any x that satisfies $0<|x|<\delta$ we have $|\frac{1}{x}+\sin x|>c$.

It's clear that : $$x>0 \implies \frac{1}{x}>0$$
$$x>0 \implies -1\leq \sin x \leq 1$$

Therefore if we choose $M=2\pi*c>0 \implies \sin x=0$.

Therefore we found $0<|x|<\delta \implies |\frac{1}{x}+\sin x|>c$ and $\sin x=0$ due to the $M$ we chose, and for $x>0 \implies \frac{1}{x}>0$. Therefore :

$$0<|x|<\delta \implies |\frac{1}{x}+\sin x|=\frac{1}{x}+\sin x= \frac{1}{x}+0 = \frac{1}{x}>c$$

Conclusion: For any $c>0$ we can find $x$ so $f(x)>c$ and since $f$ continuous we can find $0<x<\delta$ so $f(x)=c$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have to prove that there is $x_1$ that will give you $f(x_1) < c$. Then you have for some $x_0$ $f(x_0) > c$ and for some $x_1$ $f(x_1) < c$. Since $f$ is continuous there is a point $x_3 \in (x_0, x_1)$ in which $f(x_3) = c$.

Comment: Near $0$ it is big. For $x=n\pi$, $n$ big, it is close to $0$. Now Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Do you mean to choose two point so that $0<y<z<\delta$, since $f$ continuous I could use the intermediate value theorem in $[y,z]$ and there is $x \in [y,z]$ so $f(x)=c$?

Comment: @Jihad you conclude that there is $x_1f(x_1)<c$ since f continuous?

Comment: @JaVaPG no. Since if we take $\{x_k\} = 2\pi k$ and assume $k \rightarrow \infty$ then $\sin(x_k) = 0$ and $\frac{1}{x_k} \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Jihad So you mean that for $2 \pi x$ $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x}+\sin x= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x}+0=0$$ and since there are value of $f$ that are really "close" to zero therefore we can conclude that is exists $f(x_1)<c$?

Comment: @JaVaPG want to find only $1$ point. So I just took some subsequence. Since $c > 0$ and $f(x_k) \rightarrow 0$ we can find $x_K$ such that $f(x_K) < c$.

Comment: @Jihad: Yes, argue that there is a $q$ such that $f(q)\gt c$ and there is a $p$ such that $f(p)\lt c$, and use IVT on the interval $[p,q]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any $c$, consider the function $g_c(x) = 1+x\sin(x) -cx$. Given any $c>0$, there exists $n$ such that $\dfrac1n < c\pi$, by Archimedian property.

Now we have $g_c(0) = 1>0$ and $g_c(n\pi) = 1-cn\pi < 0$. Since $g_c(x)$ is continuous, by intermediate value theorem, conclude what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely true, yet not far.

The first place I noticed you did something wrong was $M=2\pi∗c>0\implies \sin(x)=0$.

1. Did you mean $\sin(M)=0$? *A priori* $\sin(x)$ isn't affected by $M$
2. The fact is that $c$ is **any** real number, not necessarily natural, so $\sin(2\pi*c)$ doesn't have to be zero.

These are my 2 cents.